# not getting the value of http_proxy using python

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables, python3

I have checked that there have an environmental variable by using this command :

```
printenv | grep http_proxy
```

and when i am trying to get this value by using python script it is returning None.here is my python script :

```
print(os.environ.get('http_proxy'))
```

i don't understand what is the wrong in this script.

Comment: Is the name possibly `HTTP_PROXY`?

Comment: i have tried by this name also bt getting the same result @GunnarHjalmarsson

Comment: ok I got the solution ...have to write in ~/.profile file.